# ConstraintViolationException - distinguish between spring a hibernate for HttpStatus

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have custom ConstraintValidator which checks @RequestParam for valid values.
I also have hibernate entities with some attributes annotated with @NotNull.

Default behavior is that ConstraintViolationException is translated to HttpStatus=500.
This is desired for error raising from hibernate (that is persisting entities and so).
But I would like to raise HttpStatus=400 for ConstraintViolations raised from @RestController.

@ExceptionHandler works but it cannot distinguish between violations raised from hibernate and spring layer. I guess both layers uses hibernate validator dependency but we should be able to distinguish among those.

```
 @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return getObjectResponseEntity(ex, request, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

I wonder if there are some other ways to achieve this. I have tried @InitBinder validator but it seems not to work with @RequestParam.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

One solution for this is to list all violations from the given exception and check if the root bean is names like *Controller but this is not quite clean solution and bound a developer to name controllers this way.

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException ex, WebRequest request) {
    // TODO ugly
    boolean isFromController = ex.getConstraintViolations().stream()
        .map(cv -> cv.getRootBeanClass().getSimpleName())
        .anyMatch(cv -> cv.contains("Controller"));
    return getObjectResponseEntity(ex, request, isFromController ? HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

The controller looks like this with the @SupportedFileTypes custom validator which checks string value against internal enum.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{requirementId}/export-cisel", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public CisRadDto exportRequirementNumbers(
    @PathVariable UUID requirementId,
    @SupportedFileTypes @RequestParam(value = "formatSouboru", required = false) String fileFormat
) {
    return pozadavekFacade.exportRequirementNumbers(requirementId, fileFormat != null ? fileFormat : "default");
}
```

pozadavekFacade only saves the created entity which has the folowing check:

```
@NotBlank
@Column(length = 10, nullable = false)
private String idUzivatele;
```

Comment: Do you have a layer in between ? or your controller is building entities directly from user input ? Maybe you can add more code snippet in your question

Comment: Actually yes. There are few layers - Facade classes using services. I am gonna edit question now with some code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code is spread across different layers you should be able to catch `ConstraintViolationException` in each of them.

So in your facade you can catch it and rethrow them as `RuntimeException` (or whatever the exception you want). Then your controller layer will map this exception to 500 internal error.

And in your controller layer keep your logic and translate `ConstraintViolationException` to a 400 bad request response.

Updated : you're not forced to add try-catch boilerplate code everywhere.

Example : (don't copy paste this code. It is just to demonstrate how you can get rid of try-catch block at multiple places)

```
class Service {

    String a() {throw new RuntimeException();}
    String b() {throw new RuntimeException();}
    String c() {throw new RuntimeException();}
}
class Facade {
    Service service;

    String a() {return tryRun(() -> service.a());}
    String b() {return tryRun(() -> service.b());}
    String c() {return tryRun(() -> service.c());}

    String tryRun(Supplier<String> run) {
        try {
            return run.get();
        }
        catch(ConstraintViolationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(""); // don't forget to extract useful information from ConstraintViolationEx type.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to avoid this because it would be try/catch everywhere.

Comment: I am looking more like for some technical global solution (lot of code to change for me) but I will use your suggestion if I do not find any other. Thank you.